# Extract certain pattern with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11gr2

I have a string like

```
with xx as (
select 'id9' idno,'untest X456789,W357987 and Q321089 cont group' test from dual)
select * from xx
```

There are some thosand rows like the following

```
       IDNO |                             TEST
      +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        id9 | untest X456789,W357987 and Q321089 cont group
```

**I want to extract words that begin with a letter followed by 6 digits. Also, there should be a comma between them** (because later I will place them to multiple rows)

**Resulting Table:**

```
        IDNO |                TEST
      +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        id9 | X456789,X321678,W357987,Q321089
```

I have tried `regexp_replace`, but could not reach a solution.

```
select idno, REGEXP_replace( test,'([^[A-Z]{1}[:digit:]{6},?])') AS test from xx
```

Comment: are you sure that your database is normalized?

Comment: It is an OLAP environment which is denormalized purposefully. (less joins, cleaner code). Above table was received from a third party institution, and unfortunately we did not have the chance to format it according to our needs.

Comment: That's ok as long as it's done on purpose and not by poor understanding of normalization. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following does what you want for your original string:

```
with xx as (
select 'id9' idno,'untest X456789,W357987 and Q321089 cont group' test from dual
)
select idno,
       REGEXP_replace(test,
                      '([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[ ,]?)|(.)', '\1'
                     ) AS test
from xx;
```

Getting the second space to be a comma . . . you can use a regular replace:

```
with xx as (
select 'id9' idno,'untest X456789,W357987 and Q321089 cont group' test from dual
)
select idno,
       replace(REGEXP_replace(test,
                              '([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[ ,]?)|(.)', '\1'
                             ),
               ' ', ',') AS test
from xx;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/15297).

Comment: Mr. Linoff, first query did not make a change in the original string. Second one just placed commas between all the words.

Comment: @bonsvr . . . I apologize for that.  I had it working in SQL Fiddle and apparently copied the wrong queries back to the answer.  Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Learned much from your book BTW.