# How to remove repeated commas and trim from each end using REGEXP_REPLACE?

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I need to concatenate several fields together, which may or may not be null. I could potentially end up with a string like: ',,c,,e,,' which I actually want to show as 'c,e'.

I can get this via a combination of `regexp_replace` and `trim`:

```
with sd as (select 'a,b,c' str from dual union all
            select 'a' str from dual union all
            select null str from dual union all
            select 'a,,,d' from dual union all
            select 'a,,,,e,f,,'from dual union all
            select ',,,d,,f,g,,'from dual)
select str,
       regexp_replace(str, '(,)+', '\1') new_str,
       trim(both ',' from regexp_replace(str, '(,)+', '\1')) trimmed_new_str
from   sd;

STR         NEW_STR     TRIMMED_NEW_STR
----------- ----------- ---------------
a,b,c       a,b,c       a,b,c          
a           a           a              

a,,,d       a,d         a,d            
a,,,,e,f,,  a,e,f,      a,e,f          
,,,d,,f,g,, ,d,f,g,     d,f,g
```

but I feel like it ought to be doable in a single `regexp_replace` only I can't work out for the life of me how it could be done!

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Query:**

```
with sd as (select 'a,b,c' str from dual union all
            select 'a' from dual  union all
            select null from dual union all
            select 'a,,,d,' from dual  union all
            select ',a,,,d' from dual  union all
            select ',a,,,d,' from dual  union all
            select ',,,a,,,d,,,' from dual  union all
            select ',a,,,,,e,f,,' from dual union all
            select ',,d,,f,g,,' from dual )
select str,
       regexp_replace(str, '^,+|,+$|,+(,\w)','\1') new_str
from   sd;
```

**Result:**

```
str             new_str
-----------------------
a,b,c           a,b,c
a               a
(null)          (null)  
a,,,d,          a,d
,a,,,d          a,d
,a,,,d,         a,d
,,,a,,,d,,,     a,d
,a,,,,,e,f,,    a,e,f
,,d,,f,g,,      d,f,g
```

**Pattern:**

```
  ^,+       matches commas at the beginning
  |         OR
  ,+$       matches commas at the end
  |         OR
  ,+(,\w)   matches several commas followed by a single comma and a word.
```

Replaces above with only first sub expression, which is a comma and word.

Comment: Perfect - no way in a million years would I have come up with that! I only just about grasp it even with your explanation *{;-) Regular expressions are hard, but extremely powerful. Many thanks!

Comment: Very interesting!  I am breaking this down trying to understand how it works. How is this not returning `',d'` when the subgroup contains a comma?: `'select regexp_replace(',,,d', '^,+|,+(,\w)', '\1') from dual;'`

Comment: May be `^,+` matches with the commas before `,+(,\w)`. Even I'm not fully sure how it works. I learnt this technique from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18017052/646591).
Also, i thought `^,+|,+$|(\w,),+` pattern should work. But, it doesn't remove trailing comma.

Answer (score -1):

Give it a try:

```
with sd as (select 'a,b,c' str union all
            select 'a' union all
            select null union all
            select 'a,,,d' union all
            select 'a,,,,,e,f,,' union all
            select ',,,d,,f,g,,')
select str,
       regexp_replace(str, '(,){2,}', '\1', 1, 0) new_str,
       trim(both ',' from regexp_replace(str, '(,){2,}', '\1', 1, 0)) trimmed_new_str
from   sd;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still requires the trim() to remove the leading/trailing commas. I'm after a regular expression that does that as well as remove repeating commas.